# make a RTL navigation Drawer in android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation, right-to-left, drawer

I want to make my navigation open from `right to left`. But as soon as I change any of these steps my program face to error force closed after click on navigation after running the app.

My main_activity.xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

My custom_toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="title"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cnews"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


//content
<include layout="@layout/content_main" /> </LinearLayout>
```

My appbar_main.xml

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />
```

My main_activity.java

```
import android.app.FragmentManager; import android.os.Bundle;  import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;  import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;  import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; import android.view.Menu;   import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.home_page) {
            Home_page_fragment homeFragment = new Home_page_fragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent , homeFragment, homeFragment.getTag()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.tour_page) {
            Tour_page_fragment tourFragment = new Tour_page_fragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent , tourFragment, tourFragment.getTag()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.lstour_page) {
            LsTour_page_fragment LstourFragment = new LsTour_page_fragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent , LstourFragment, LstourFragment.getTag()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.hotel_page) {

        } else if (id == R.id.agency_page) {

        } else if (id == R.id.news_page) {

        }else if (id == R.id.logbook_page) {

        }else if (id == R.id.message_page) {

        }else if (id == R.id.favorite_page) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    } }
```

I changed `"Start" to "end"` in `.xml` main activity and `java` main activity get force closed!

I change "start" to "right" get force closed!!

I used `RTL library` but again get forced closed!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by force close? Are you getting any error?

Comment: no my adb logcat is empty!!  dont't show any error!  but when i click on navigation drawer in app the programe closed!

Comment: Which version of support library you use?

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0'

Comment: You're getting an `IllegalArgumentException`, since `ActionBarDrawerToggle` only works with drawers that have `START` gravity, out of the box. You really should try to figure out how to get the stack trace in the logcat, as it will be very helpful to know how to do so in the future.

Comment: I definitely use logcat and trace it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your customized Gravity is not defined and returns NULL.
First of all, you should update your `menu.xml` and build an item as an icon for right menu, like this:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_right"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:title="@string/action_menuright"
/>
```

And in `main_activity.java` disable the default toggle drawer which opened from left and update this:

```
toggle.syncState();
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);//this is added line
```

and similary udate this one:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
         <   here:  add this line:  >
    DrawerLayout drawer;
```

and finally change this class to:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menu_right) {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT) ) {
             drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        else{
             drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and everything is fine now.

Comment: With this solution, the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is not used at all, so you can just remove it, rather than initializing it, and then disabling it.

Comment: I agree. this is a typed solution and I didn't focus on this, maybe there is no need for some sections anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that use this code to Oncreate `main_activity.java` :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```