# How to set Navigation Drawer icons to the right side of the Item Texts?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

My Project Screenshot: [My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Z1e.png)

My Target Design: [My Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HyZQ.jpg)

I have created a (right to left) navigation drawer. It's working fine but when I'm trying to move the icon from the left side to the right side, it's not working.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/nav"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="#d2a967"
    app:itemTextColor="#d2a967"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Attention: My API is 14+

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101725/make-a-rtl-navigation-drawer-in-android) can help, create a custom toolbar like him.

Comment: Refer this Answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547277/how-to-set-navigation-drawer-to-be-opened-from-right-to-left

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33464417/8476022

Comment: Refer this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547277/how-to-set-navigation-drawer-to-be-opened-from-right-to-left

Comment: And a quick fix `getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);`.

Answer (score 2):

**Add to your Activity before setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);:**

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
```

This is only possible on API 17+

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if ActionBar provide such feature . But you can do it by just using a menu item .
Create a Menu on extreme right:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_action_Drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/item_menu_drawer"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Then OnmenuItem click Open/Close the Drawer:-

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_action_Drawer:
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this open your Navigation drawer right side if your target  API is 17+

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
      getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
  }
```

Try this Create a new Layout like below

```
 <TextView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/tv_badge"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

than set Custom view to Your navigation view using below code

```
 YourNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setActionView(R.layout.custom_layout);
```

> **[setActionView(int resId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html)**
>
> Set an action view for this menu item.

**EDIT**

> try this to modify your single navigation menu item

```
TextView  textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
textView.setText("ONE");
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary));
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setActionView(textView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to change following in your code.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) //call this before super.onCreate
private void forceRtlIfSupported() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
}
```

In

`AndroidManifiest.xml`

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

**NOTE** : This will work from API 16 and above version.