# how to customize nevegation_menu in android using menu item.xml

Tags: android, layout, menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_profile"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_my_profile" />
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">


        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_merge"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_merge_contact"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_merge" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_export"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_merge_contact"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_export" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_notifications" />
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_app"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_rate"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_rate" />
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_report"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_report"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_report" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_faq"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_faq"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_faq" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_about" />

    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_logout" />
    </group>


</menu>
```

this is my `navigationmenu.xml`

my current Screen  using given `xml` is below.

[image]

my expected screen is below i have  all image i just want separate all item in group like given screen also i want set **border and background** with white please suggest me how to do this i am unable to do this i dont know how to achieve my expected screen is below

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom navigation drawer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Comment: how i will change using menu.xml or some layout we need to create @Benjithbinja i am not able to see how they change i have to do using menuitem.xml can u please tell me

Comment: @MakleeLee this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071680/7666442